# MLT Framework : Specifying File PATH for QText producer

Tags: mlt

I was able to realize Ticker text using QText and demo examples on gitHub, unfortunately I am facing a problem in setting up file source and  font.

```
melt colour:black out=299 -track A_David_Beckham.mp4 out=299
-track qtext:"Scroll.txt" bgcolour=0xff000080 out=299
-transition composite start=0/0:1920x1000 end=0/0:1920x1000 distort=1 a_track=0 b_track=1 out=299
-transition composite a_track=0 b_track=1 out=299 distort=1 start=0/1000:200%x64:100
-transition composite a_track=0 b_track=2 out=299 titles=1 start=100%/1000:200%x64 end=-299%/1000:200%x64 halign=left valign=bottom
```

Someone please help me move forward.

1. Significance of `b_track=2` in 3rd transition above, (sorry appears as dumb question, possibly please bear with me here)
2. How do I set test this for a Chinease font? How do I know how many fonts are supported and which one I can specify?
3. How do I give a file with Chinease text as input and set encoding as Unicode?

Regards,
Abhijit

Answer (score 0):

1. You have 3 tracks. If you do make a transition to somehow blend/mix/combine them, then active content on the highest order track is used. This transition composite the text on track 2 onto the black background on track 0. What is a little strange is two transitions between tracks 0 and 1 defined for the same time periods. It is unclear what the result will be and probably a mistake.
2. It uses the fonts of your OS. On Linux, learn about fontconfig or just look for Chinese font packages from your distro.
3. The input is assumed to be UTF-8. To give a file name: qtext:{filename}